# What side-effects arise from setting a Long variable equal to False?

Tags: vb6, boolean, long-integer

I am working on a piece of legacy code at work and I ran into a variable assignment that raises some questions for me. The variable `PortOpen` was declared with its type set as `Long`, and later in the code it was set equal to `False`. Since the integer value of `False` is `0`, I assume that this will just mean the `PortOpen` will be `0` until it is modified, but I am suspicious that this might introduce some subtle bugs. A `Long` is twice the size of a `Boolean` in this case, so is there any possibility for an error when later using `PortOpen` in a logic comparison? Or, just in general, are there any quirks or other effects of using this type of variable assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course a bad thing as it is confusing for a person reading the code, but as long as you use 0/False for the false values and -1/True for true values the program should work fine.

You need to watch out for using 1 for True, as that will give you ambigous results.  1 (or in fact any value other than 0) will give you True in logical comparisons, so this will display "True":

```
Dim myvar As Long

myvar = 2
If myvar Then
    MsgBox "True"
Else
    MsgBox "False"
End If
```

However, the problem arises when you apply a "Not" to this expression.  Generally you would expect "Not True" to be "False", but the following code will display "True":

```
Dim myvar As Long

myvar = 2
If Not myvar Then
    MsgBox "True"
Else
    MsgBox "False"
End If
```

So, apart from being bad for readability of your code, using Integer or Long for booleans CAN lead to errors in your code.

Answer (score 3):

As you say `PortOpen` will be `0` after the automatic conversion of `True` to a `Long`, there are no other side effects of this assignment.

Aside from being bad practice & confusing for others the only other potential problem would be any assumption that `PortOpen = 1 = True` which is not the case as `Clng(True)` is `-1`.

Personally I would replace the assignemtnet with `0` or a `0` `CLOSED` symbolic constant/enum.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I agree with your suggested change, but the source code was written by the boss' brother, so it might take some work to get it implemented -_- It kills me to just leave something ambiguous like that in the source, but I needed to know if that would work as a last-resort option.